# R: How to apply for loop for only subsetted rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, geospatial

I have a dataframe

```
head(df)
                 time     LON     LAT MAG
1 1965-01-12 13:32:25 87.8286 27.3829 6.1
2 1965-01-12 13:55:20 87.6567 27.3269 5.3
3 1965-02-18 04:26:36 94.1127 25.0251 5.5
4 1965-02-25 10:34:07 94.5712 23.6672 5.3
5 1965-04-11 22:33:05 92.2023 26.6941 5.1
6 1965-04-30 07:13:25 95.8880 28.3319 4.4
```

It's the time, location and magnitude of earthquakes and contains about 4000 rows.

I have subsetted the `MAG >= 5` events and for each such event I'd like to check within the next 10 days of the event. And then output the events that are within a 50 km radius in this 10 day time window for each `MAG >= 5` event.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(geosphere)

t <- filter(df, MAG >= 5) 

for (i in 1:nrow(t)){
  data1 <- filter(t, time <= time[i] + days(10) & time >= time[i])
  p <- select(data1, LON, LAT)
  l <- distm(p)[1,]            # first row of the distance matrix between each event
  for (j in 1:length(l)){
    if (l[j] <= 50000 & l[j] != 0){       # within 50 kms and excluding the event itself
      print(data1[j,])
    }
  }
}
```

But this only checks for values in the dataframe `t`. How do I check within next 10 days of a `MAG >= 5` event in the original dataframe `df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a set based approach using `merge` and avoid nested `for` loops. Specifically, run a subsetted cross join matching earthquakes over 5 mag with every other earthquake event within 10 days and 50 km. At N=4,000 rows below should be feasible. Below uses base R code but can be adjusted for dplyr methods (`filter`, `inner_join`, `arrange`).

```
mag5_df <- subset(df, MAG >= 5) 

# CROSS JOIN PAIRING OF MAG 5 EVENTS AND ALL OTHER EARTHQUAKES WITHIN 10 DAYS
merge_df <- subset(merge(mag5, df, by=NULL, suffixes=c("", "_")), 
                   time_ >= time & time_ <= time + lubridate::days(10))

# CALCULATE DISTANCE BETWEEN LAT/LON PAIRS
merge_df$dist_m <- geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid(merge_df[c("LON", "LAT")], 
                                                    merge_df[c("LON_", "LAT_")])

# SUBSET TO WITHIN 50 KM AND ORDER OUTPUT BY MAG 5 LAT/LON, TIME, AND DISTANCE
near50km_df <- subset(merge_df, dist_m > 0 & dist_m <= 5E4)
near50km_df <- data.frame(with(near50km_df, near50km_df[order(LAT, LON, time, dist_m),],
                          row.names = NULL)

# DISPLAY ALL MAG 5 EVENTS AND QUALIFIED PAIRS
near50km_df
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This approach is new for me. I just don't understand what's the purpose of the ```order``` function here? Also just for clarification: The ```distm``` function should be replaced by something like the ```distHeaversine``` function. Beacuse the ```distm``` function gives a distance matrix which wouldn't work here.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Regarding `order`, this is simply aesthetic to re-order rows to better see the pairwise matches. And yes adjust distance calculations for single vector return be it `distHaversine`, `distMeeus`, `distVincentyEllipsoid`, and others available in [`geosphere`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-10). Arguably, the Vincenty is most accurate (but more time to compute) given Earth's spherical shape.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for clarifying.